# intermittent errors - making jquery ajax request inside the success/error function of a jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

**jQuery ajax request inside the success/error function of another jquery ajax request:**

I am having problems with an html page, that makes a jquery ajax request inside the success/error function of a another jquery ajax request.

This works OK on desktop, but on Blackberry Z10 mobile device, it throws http 400 or 500 errors occasionally.  Response time is of course much better on desktop, so latency issues may be non-existent. It used to work on older BB device, but then we were using jQ-1.6.1 now jQ-1.9.1.  Maybe there was a change in behaviour in jQ versions?

I put the logic in a loop and am able to reproduce a **3-5% failure rate**. Is there a good reason for this pattern to fail?  Is there a better way to do this?

I have reproduced a skeleton of the program below.

```
<script>
    function fnFirstFunction(){ 

    var XMLOutput = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><myData></myData>";

    $.ajax({
        url: 'mypgm.pgm',
        dataType: 'xml',        
        type: 'POST',       
        data: 'data=' + XMLOutput , 
        success: function(xml) {                
            fnPerformSometingElse();
        },

        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("error error");
        } 
    });
}   

function fnPerformSometingElse(){       

    $.ajax({            
        url: 'AnotherPgm.pgm',
        dataType:   'xml',
        type:       'POST',
        context:    myContext,
        data:       'newData=123' + ticketNo ,
        success: function(xml){

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){                                                 
        });
}       

 $(document).ready(function()  {     

     var myVar=setInterval(function(){
        myTimer()
     }, 2000);

    function myTimer(){
        fnFirstFunction();
    }
 });

</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id='loop'>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if you are getting some 500 error codes it would suggest errors happening on the server (maybe because of the format of the request) - try checking the server error logs for clues

Comment: You shouldn't use an interval, use a timeout instead and recall it on complete callback of second request and error callback of first one. What can happen using your code is that some requests are aborted